# jQuery Waypoints Error: The sticky method does not exist

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-waypoints

I want to stick an element to the top of the page in WordPress, using [jQuery Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/) plugin.

```
<script src="path/to/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $('#myelement').waypoint('sticky');
</script>
```

But the console says:

> Error: The sticky method does not exist in jQuery Waypoints.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Did you include the **sticky shortcut script** on top of your normal `waypoints.js`?

```
<script src="path/to/waypoints.min.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/waypoints-sticky.min.js"></script>
```

See [Sources](https://github.com/imakewebthings/jquery-waypoints/tree/master/shortcuts/sticky-elements) and [Docs](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/shortcuts/sticky-elements/)

Comment: Make sure you include them in this order as well.  I had that problem :p

Answer (score 4):

Another thing that can happen to users may be , the js adds the sticky css to the element but the css is empty.

Adding :

```
.stuck{position: fixed; top: 0;}
```

to your css file will stick it.

Comment: could be, but would not produce the error message "The sticky method does not exist in jQuery Waypoints" as described in the question.

Comment: thank you, this helper a lot, i didn't know that i should implement that myself.